# Bitmap image attachment to outlook 365 email

Tags: .net, image, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm able to successfully create a bitmap object and save it locally. What I would like to do though is either embed this image into the email or save it into the memory stream and add it as an attachment to the email.

I've tried the code below with some success:

```
 using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);


                string tempFilePath = Path.GetTempPath() + "test.jpg";
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create);

                stream.CopyTo(fs);
                fs.Close();
                mailItem.Attachments.Add(tempFilePath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, "test.jpg");



            }
```

The issue is that when I open this image, I get the message "It looks like we don't support this file format". I'm not sure why this issue is happening. I've already tried to convert the image to base 64 and then attempting to use it in an html tag, but it doesn't seem like image embedding is supported in this version of outlook. Your assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by saving the image locally, attaching to the email by value, and then using SetProperty.

//Append a guid to randomize the file name
                string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

```
            string SchemaPR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E";

            //Get the user's directory path to temp
            string tempFilePath = Path.GetTempPath() + $"screenShotImage{id}.jpg";

            //Save the screenshot in Temp
            bitmap.Save(tempFilePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            //Attach the screenshot to the email
            mailItem.Attachments.Add(tempFilePath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, $"Timeline Graph for Release {releaseId}.jpg");
            mailItem.Attachments[mailItem.Attachments.Count].PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(SchemaPR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, id);

            //Clean up the file that we stored
            if ((System.IO.File.Exists(tempFilePath)))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(tempFilePath);
            }

            //Display the image into the email
            string banner = string.Format(@"<br/><a href='{0}' ><img src='cid:{1}' ></a></body>", $"{url}/release/timeline{releaseId}", id);
            mailItem.HTMLBody = mailItem.HTMLBody.Replace("</body>", banner);
```